# how can i get word from arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I made an arraylist `data` and when I do

```
int last=data.size();
int random = r.nextInt(last) + 0;
string a = ""+data.get(random).toString();
```

`a` gets the address of the data.

Comment: And *what* exactly is your problem?

Comment: If you have a `List<String> data`. Doing a `data.get(index)` will return you the `String` in that `index` position. If you have a problem with the content, check what you put in it (or simply debug your code to check the content at runtime). Having like you said a "_address of the data_", it could be a POJO, then implements `toString` in that class (`Object.toString()` returns what you see). A [mcve] would be nice in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , `data.get(random)` returns you the object from the list. Since, you are calling data.get(random).toString(), you are getting the string representation which by default returns the hexadecimal characters.
Try the following:
a. Perform your code with a list of String. -> it should return the string at that index position(random).
b. 
Try overriding the toString() method inside you java object, you will get the output from your toString() method of the java object,.